# log-log models vs margins eyex() for elasticities

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, estimation, stata, elasticity

I'm trying to estimate the elasticity between debt and interest rate for different values of interest. I am using a time series dataset.

I made a categorical variable for interest so that I can group the observations when running my regressions as I am interested in
the elasticity between debt and interest rate for certain groups of observations.

My first option:
using a log-log model

```
reg lnDebt lnInterest + control variables if categorical_variable_for_interest==1
```

My second option is

```
xi: reg Debt Interest + control variables
margins eyex(Interest) over(categorical_variable_for_interest)
```

I get different estimates for the elasticity between debt and interest for the same group of observations.
If I understood the `margins, eyex()` command correctly it simply takes the natural log  of the chosen variables to calculate d(log f)/d(log x).
Does the `eyex` command give a more exact estimate?

Comment: (1) If this is a time series, you should use some sort of time series models. At the very least, with Newey-West standard errors, which would make it `newey` rather than `regress`. (2) you don't have the same groups of observations and you don't have the same model; your second regression uses more data, and you assume additive main effects, while the first regression assumes multiplicative effects. There is no way on earth you'd get the same answers from these two models. (3) unless you have a really old version of Stata, you should not be using `xi`, but factor variable notation instead.

Comment: I think your understanding of what `margins, eyex()` is doing can be helped by: `sysuse auto, clear`
`reg price mpg i.foreign` 
`predict yhat`
`gen eps = _b[mpg]*mpg/yhat`
`sum eps`
`margins, eyex(mpg)`

Comment: you should not use the `xi` prefix when you want to use `margins`.

Comment: @StasK 
Thanks for a good answer.
I'm very new to stata and it does feel like a jungle sometimes. Then using  newey(or other time series model) rather than reg and then the postestimation margins would be a cleaner and better way to go. Rather than running individual log-log models for each span of interest rates I'm interested in. As I get everything in a single model, using all observations and so on.
This is probably really basic I'm just a bit confused from reading the different online stata manuals.